# OLS regression using the CAPM model in python

Tags: multiple-regression, finance, statsmodels

I've checked several posts here and haven't found what I'm looking for... The goal is to do a CAPM regression and assume that you have the following information:

- monthly prices for company AAPL, S&P500(call it sp) and the 10 year treasury (call it bond)
- you make the following adjustmets to make sure your data is correct

  - take log returns for AAPL(raapl) and SP(rsp), so you have monthly returns
  - divide bond by 12 * 100 to have monthly returns(rbond), i.e. the monthly risk free rate
  - compute the corresponding risk premiums, i.e.

    - rpaapl = raapl - rbond
    - rpsp = rsp - rbond

So going by the CAPM formula, $R_{aapl} = R_f + \beta(R_m - R_f) = R_{bond} + \beta(R_{sp} - R_{bond})$ 
My question is that I've seen CAPM done as per the first set of code below instead of the second one. I understand that the CAPM formula can be manipulated to yield, $R_{aapl} - R_{bond} = \beta(R_{sp} - R_{bond})$ so that it would seem that both regressions are equivalent, however, they yield different retults. Could you correct where my thinking is off?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
est = smf.ols(formula='rpaapl ~ rpsp', data=returns).fit()
print(est.summary())
print(est.conf_int())
```

Results in:
[image: first regression]

Whereas this code:

```
est = smf.ols(formula='raapl ~ rbond + rpsp + 0', data=returns).fit()
print(est.summary())
print(est.conf_int())
```

Results in:
[image]

Comment: the biggest difference is that you have intercept in the first piece, and not in the second. in CAPM there's no intercept

Comment: Thank you. It seems from other sources that the "est = smf.ols(formula='rpaapl ~ rpsp', data=returns).fit()" method is the correct one.